# PHP DateTime microseconds always returns 0

Tags: php, datetime

this code always returns 0 in PHP 5.2.5 for microseconds:

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime();
echo $dt->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u") . "\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
[root@www1 ~]$ php date_test.php
2008-10-03T20:31:26.000000
[root@www1 ~]$ php date_test.php
2008-10-03T20:31:27.000000
[root@www1 ~]$ php date_test.php
2008-10-03T20:31:27.000000
[root@www1 ~]$ php date_test.php
2008-10-03T20:31:28.000000
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u") have less overhead?

Comment: Maybe you're too lucky ;)

Comment: @Unkwntech: date() only supports integers. The manual forwards you to date_format/DateTime::format for using 'u'.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski: yes, i am using DateTime::format

Comment: From http://us.php.net/date:
Note: Since this function only accepts integer timestamps the u format character is only useful when using the date_format() function with user based timestamps created with date_create().

Does this mean i have to manually build it with microtime()?

Comment: This is ridiculous. Came here with same problem as OP. What a mess.

Comment: Ridiculous indeed...2014 now.

Comment: we can assume will be the same for 2015

Comment: It would appear user652649 was correct...

Comment: we can see the same thing in 2016

Comment: Note that PHP 7 (I only tried on PHP 7.1) adds microseconds by default so there there is no problem anymore.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This seems to work, although it seems illogical that http://us.php.net/date documents the microsecond specifier yet doesn't really support it:

```
function getTimestamp()
{
        return date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s") . substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8);
}
```

Comment: By doing separate calls you have a small chance of two time stamps being out of order: eg call date at 1:29:22.999999 and mircotime at 1:29:23.000001. On my server consecutive calls are about 10 us apart.

Comment: try: list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime()); return date (date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", $sec) . $usec;

Comment: @eydelber : Since the PHP date() function only accepts integer timestamps the u format character is only useful when using the date_format() function with user based timestamps created with date_create().

Comment: Good simple solution for the simple problem I was looking for. :)

Comment: This accepted answer induces indeed a race condition. @Lucky's solution is a much better workaround to cope with PHP weirdness.

Comment: @Lucky your code is not formated correctly there and adds an additional zero to seconds, see my answer for corrections. :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/38334226/614616

Comment: The digits format is correct but its accuracy is questionable. It's not a formatting of what time but a concatenation of two times. With an unknown gap between them.

Answer (score 20):

You can specify that your input contains microseconds when constructing a `DateTime` object, and use `microtime(true)` directly as the input.

Unfortunately, this will fail if you hit an exact second, because there will be no `.` in the microtime output; so use `sprintf` to force it to contain a `.0` in that case:

```
date_create_from_format(
    'U.u', sprintf('%.f', microtime(true))
)->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO');
```

Or equivalently (more OO-style)

```
DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'U.u', sprintf('%.f', microtime(true))
)->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO');
```

Comment: This one will fail if `microtime(true)` hits a full sec - `date_create_from_format('U.u', sprintf('%.f', microtime(true)))->format(...`

Comment: This will also fail on PHP 5.3.2 (Ubuntu 10.04) which returns False when 'U.u' is used as the format in this function (bug)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution requires PHP 5.3+

Answer (score 17):

This function pulled from https://www.php.net/date

```
function udate($format, $utimestamp = null)
{
    if (is_null($utimestamp))
        $utimestamp = microtime(true);

    $timestamp = floor($utimestamp);
    $milliseconds = round(($utimestamp - $timestamp) * 1000000);

    return date(preg_replace('`(?<!\\\\)u`', $milliseconds, $format), $timestamp);
}

echo udate('H:i:s.u'); // 19:40:56.78128
```

Very screwy you have to implement this function to get "u" to work... :\

Comment: Hi, what about (string)microtime(), 1, 8?

Comment: +1 for using a negative lookbehind in order to not replace `\u`.

Comment: h2ooooooo, it isn't right solution anyway, it doesn't support  escaped backslash itself, i.e. "\\u"

Answer (score 15):

Try this and it shows micro seconds:

```
$t = microtime(true);
$micro = sprintf("%06d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000000);
$d = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro,$t) );

print $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u");
```

Comment: Fairly elegant, I like this solution best. I've did some tests and didn't find any problems with this implementation.

Comment: Great, got anything as elegant to convert back to a microtime?

Comment: Since you're concatenating the microseconds onto a formatted string anyway, you don't need the `DateTime` object: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro,$t)` is aready the desired string (or equivalently `date('Y-m-d H:i:s.',$t).$micro`)

Answer (score 8):

```
\DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
```

Will give you (at least on most systems):

```
object(DateTime)(
  'date' => '2015-03-09 17:27:39.456200',
  'timezone_type' => 3,
  'timezone' => 'Australia/Darwin'
)
```

But there is a loss of precision because of PHP float rounding. It's not truly microseconds.

**Update**

This is probably the best compromise of the `createFromFormat()` options, and provides full precision.

```
\DateTime::createFromFormat('0.u00 U', microtime());
```

**gettimeofday()**

More explicit, and maybe more robust. Solves the bug found by Xavi.

```
$time = gettimeofday(); 
\DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', sprintf('%d.%06d', $time['sec'], $time['usec']));
```

Comment: I am curious about "on most system" statement. Is it a problem of host time resolution or DateTime implementation on certain systems?

Comment: I don't understand: which is this "float precision issue" you refer to? Can I use safely simply `\DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));`?

Comment: I've just answered that in another question. Basically, microtime(true) will lose precision because it's stored as a float. It won't actually give you microseconds, but 10ths of milliseconds. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390315/what-is-the-highest-date-precision-in-php

Comment: Very good point at the float rounding and getting `00` at the end! The `gettimeofday()` solution worked like a charm!

Comment: OOPS ERROR!! WARNING!! - I Found a bug. Case: When the number of microseconds is in the lowest 1/10th. For example: If `{seconds:1498953412,microseconds:13}` then the UTC represented is `2017-07-01T23:56:52.130000Z` and it should be `2017-07-01T23:56:52.000013Z` just because it is concatenating `1498953412` + `.` + `13` yielding in: `1498953412.13` while it should result in `1498953412.000013` - This can be problematic in logging and sequenced-events if they happen too close one from each other.

Comment: I think I found a neater solution to the zero-padding problem. But I also found a tidier solution using microtime()...

Answer (score 6):

Right, I'd like to clear this up once and for all.

An explanation of how to display the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format date & time in PHP with **milli**seconds and **micro**seconds...

***milli**seconds or 'ms' have 4 digits after the decimal point e.g. 0.1234. **micro**seconds or 'µs' have 7 digits after decimal. Seconds fractions/names explanation [here](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-millisecond.htm)*

PHP's `date()` function does not behave entirely as expected with milliseconds or microseconds as it will only except an integer, as explained in the [php date docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) under format character 'u'.

Based on Lucky's comment idea ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169428/php-datetime-microseconds-always-returns-0#comment1068246_169458)), but with corrected PHP syntax and properly handling seconds formatting *(Lucky's code added an incorrect extra '0' after the seconds)*

These also eliminate race conditions and correctly formats the seconds.

### PHP Date with **milli**seconds

Working Equivalent of `date('Y-m-d H:i:s').".$milliseconds";`

```
list($sec, $usec) = explode('.', microtime(true));
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s.', $sec) . $usec;
```

Output = `2016-07-12 16:27:08.5675`

### PHP Date with **micro**seconds

Working Equivalent of `date('Y-m-d H:i:s').".$microseconds";` or `date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u')` if the date function behaved as expected with microseconds/`microtime()`/'u'

```
list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $sec) . substr($usec, 1);
```

Output = `2016-07-12 16:27:08.56752900`

Comment: good answer, but actually a millisecond is to 3 decimal places and a microsecond is to 6, and neither of which are technically valid in a true ISO 8601 format.

Comment: Also worth noting that `DateTime::createFromFormat("U.u", $t)` **would even fail** (rather than just losing precision) if `$t` had 7 (or any more than 6) digits after the decimal point, in PHP...

Answer (score 4):

This has worked for me and is a simple three-liner:

```
function udate($format='Y-m-d H:i:s.', $microtime=NULL) {
    if(NULL === $microtime) $microtime = microtime();
    list($microseconds,$unix_time) = explode(' ', $microtime);
    return date($format,$unix_time) . array_pop(explode('.',$microseconds));
}
```

This, by default (no params supplied) will return a string in this format for the current microsecond it was called:

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.UUUUUUUU

An even simpler/faster one (albeit, with only half the precision) would be as follows:

```
function udate($format='Y-m-d H:i:s.', $microtime=NULL) {
    if(NULL === $microtime) $microtime = microtime(true);
    list($unix_time,$microseconds) = explode('.', $microtime);
    return date($format,$unix_time) . $microseconds;
}
```

This one would print out in the following format:

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.UUUU

Answer (score 1):

[date_create](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php)

> time: String in a format accepted by strtotime(), defaults to "now".

[strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

> time: The string to parse, according to the GNU » Date Input Formats syntax. Before PHP 5.0.0, microseconds weren't allowed in the time, since PHP 5.0.0 they are allowed but ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Working from [Lucky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145709/lucky)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169428/php-datetime-microseconds-always-returns-0/169458#169458) and this [feature request in the PHP bug database](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49779), I use something like this:

```
class ExtendedDateTime extends DateTime {
    /**
     * Returns new DateTime object.  Adds microtime for "now" dates
     * @param string $sTime
     * @param DateTimeZone $oTimeZone 
     */
    public function __construct($sTime = 'now', DateTimeZone $oTimeZone = NULL) {
        // check that constructor is called as current date/time
        if (strtotime($sTime) == time()) {
            $aMicrotime = explode(' ', microtime());
            $sTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s.' . $aMicrotime[0] * 1000000, $aMicrotime[1]);
        }

        // DateTime throws an Exception with a null TimeZone
        if ($oTimeZone instanceof DateTimeZone) {
            parent::__construct($sTime, $oTimeZone);
        } else {
            parent::__construct($sTime);
        }
    }
}

$oDate = new ExtendedDateTime();
echo $oDate->format('Y-m-d G:i:s.u');
```

Output:

```
2010-12-01 18:12:10.146625
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$micro_date = microtime();
$date_array = explode(" ",$micro_date);
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$date_array[1]);
echo "Date: $date:" . $date_array[0]."<br>";
```

**Sample Output**

> > 2013-07-17 08:23:37:0.88862400

Answer (score 1):

This should be the most flexible and precise:

```
function udate($format, $timestamp=null) {
    if (!isset($timestamp)) $timestamp = microtime();
    // microtime(true)
    if (count($t = explode(" ", $timestamp)) == 1) {
        list($timestamp, $usec) = explode(".", $timestamp);
        $usec = "." . $usec;
    }
    // microtime (much more precise)
    else {
        $usec = $t[0];
        $timestamp = $t[1];
    }
    // 7 decimal places for "u" is maximum
    $date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s' . substr(sprintf('%.7f', $usec), 1), $timestamp));
    return $date->format($format);
}
echo udate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u") . "\n";
echo udate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u", microtime(true)) . "\n";
echo udate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u", microtime()) . "\n";
/* returns:
2015-02-14T14:10:30.472647
2015-02-14T14:10:30.472700
2015-02-14T14:10:30.472749
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

String in a format accepted by strtotime()
It work!

Answer (score 0):

Inside of an application I am writing I have the need to set/display microtime on DateTime objects.  It seems the only way to get the DateTime object to recognize microseconds is to initialize it with the time in format of "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.uuuuuu".  The space in between the date and time portions can also be a "T" as is usual in ISO8601 format.

The following function returns a DateTime object initialized to the local timezone (code can be modified as needed of course to suit individual needs):

```
// Return DateTime object including microtime for "now"
function dto_now()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
    $usec = substr($usec, 2, 6);
    $datetime_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s\.', $sec).$usec;
    return new DateTime($datetime_now, new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP documentation clearly says "*Note that date() will always generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter...*". If you want a quick replacement for `date()` function use below function:

```
function date_with_micro($format, $timestamp = null) {
    if (is_null($timestamp) || $timestamp === false) {
        $timestamp = microtime(true);
    }
    $timestamp_int = (int) floor($timestamp);
    $microseconds = (int) round(($timestamp - floor($timestamp)) * 1000000.0, 0);
    $format_with_micro = str_replace("u", $microseconds, $format);
    return date($format_with_micro, $timestamp_int);
}
```

(available as gist here: [date_with_micro.php](https://gist.github.com/m-manu/6248802))

Comment: Note that you can use above `date_with_micro()` with same parameters you would use `date()` function.

Comment: If you read the OP's case carefully, you'll notice that `DateTime::format()` also generates *000000*

Answer (score 0):

Building on Lucky’s comment, I wrote a simple way to store messages on the server. In the past I’ve used hashes and increments to get unique file names, but the date with micro-seconds works well for this application.

```
// Create a unique message ID using the time and microseconds
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    $messageID = date("Y-m-d H:i:s ", $sec) . substr($usec, 2, 8);
    $fname = "./Messages/$messageID";

    $fp = fopen($fname, 'w');
```

This is the name of the output file:

```
2015-05-07 12:03:17 65468400
```

Answer (score 0):

Some answers make use of several timestamps, which is conceptually wrong, and overlapping issues may occur: seconds from `21:15:05.999` combined by microseconds from `21:15:06.000` give `21:15:05.000`.

Apparently the simplest is to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) with `U.u`, but [as stated in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169428/php-datetime-microseconds-always-returns-0#comment-12220584), it fails if there are no microseconds.

So, I'm suggesting this code:

```
function udate($format, $time = null) {

    if (!$time) {
        $time = microtime(true);
    }

    // Avoid missing dot on full seconds: (string)42 and (string)42.000000 give '42'
    $time = number_format($time, 6, '.', '');

    return DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', $time)->format($format);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my one-liner solution:

```php
\DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.uP');
```

Output: 2023-08-11 10:15:50.004500+00:00

Answer (score -1):

This method is safer than the accepted answer:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s.') . str_pad(substr((float)microtime(), 2), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

Output:

```
2012-06-01 12:00:13.036613
```

**Update: Not recommended** (see comments)

Comment: Bad idea. Get the microtime first (use microtime(true) instead of casting it as a float). Use the fraction portion (the microtime) and pass the integer portion as the 2nd param to date(). Otherwise you risk mismatch.

Comment: @Encoderer: What do you mean by mismatch risk? Could you give an example?

Comment: Suppose the actual time is 2012-08-12 13:53:30.9999. Your call to date() returns '2012-08-12 13:53:30'. Your subsequent call to microtime(), one ten-thousandth of a second later, returns 00 (the second ticked-over between the two calls).  

While that is an edge case, it's still a circumstance where your code will be broken. If I'm using this code to create an audit-log of events traveling through my system, you've just changed history. The right answer here is to do  a single call to microtime(true) and using that result.

Comment: oneliner: date("Y-m-d H:i:s.", $m = microtime(1)) . str_pad(floor(fmod($m, 1)*1e+6), 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

Answer (score -2):

date('u') is supported only from PHP 5.2. Your PHP may be older!