# Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_parse_from_format()

Tags: php, zend-framework, php-5.2

I'm using PHP 5.2 and getting the following error message:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_parse_from_format()`

Here is the code:

```
$startData = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s:uO", $when->startTime);
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php), `date_parse_from_format` is available since PHP 5.3 only.

You can try with this alternative, posted in SO: [PHP date_parse_from_format( ) alternative in PHP 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668223/php-date-parse-from-format-alternative-in-php-5-2)