# date_parse_from_format() returns incorrect year

Tags: php, date

I'm learning PHP and I've been trying to get a two digit representation of a year from the array returned by the `date_parse_from_format()` function:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$now = date('d.m.Y G:i:s');
$dateArray = date_parse_from_format("j.n.y H:iP", $now);
echo $dateArray['year'];
```

When I run this code, it prints 2020 on the browser instead of 14 as I expect. Please what am I missing in this code and how do I get the two digit year representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$now = date('d.m.y G:i:s');
$dateArray = date_parse_from_format("j.n.Y H:iP", $now);
echo $dateArray['year'];
```

Comment: Thanks, Anand, this works even though I find this funny since [The PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) states that the `Y` format in dates returns dates with 4 digits.

Comment: @che-azeh: uppercase yes, there is also lowercase `y`.

Answer (score 0):

edit:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$now = date('d.m.y G:i:s');
$dateArray = date_parse_from_format("j.n.Y H:iP", $now);
echo $dateArray['year'];
?>
```

`date_parse_from_format()` is available only in PHP 5.3,
Check this question as well,

[PHP date_parse_from_format( ) alternative in PHP 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668223/php-date-parse-from-format-alternative-in-php-5-2)

Comment: Still returns 4 digits, Surabhil.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$now = date('d.m.Y G:i:s');
$n = date ('j.n.y H:iP', strtotime($now)); //Convert to format you want
$dateArray = date_parse_from_format("j.n.y H:iP", $n);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($dateArray);
echo '</pre>';`
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Rana, but it still returns the year in 4 digits.