# How to get system time in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to get this output:

```
2013072708410102
```

which is year/month/day/hour/minutes/seconds/milliseconds.

I tried this:

```
$getDate = date("Ymd");
$getTime = time();

echo $getDate . " " . $getTime;
```

I am getting this kind of output:

```
201307271374885743
```

The year/month/day is correct. But I dont think its giving me the time format that I wanted.

How can I have this format 2013072708410102
year/month/day/hour/minutes/seconds/milliseconds?

Comment: You can get your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169428/php-datetime-microseconds-always-returns-0

Comment: It's all in here as well: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo date("YmdHis").str_pad((int)((($time = microtime(1)) - (int)$time) * 1000), 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

gives: `20130727024937671` to me, what should what you expect.

`date("YmdHis")` gives the *year/month/day/hour/minutes/seconds* part.

`str_pad((int)((($time = microtime(1)) - (int)$time) * 1000), 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)` is for the milliseconds.

Comment: I know, it's a bit ugly to get the milliseconds, but when there's a better way, please show it me :-)

Comment: QKWS, I am only curious, why are miliseconds so important ? Aren't you allowed to simply append three zeroes?

Comment: @Stano THIS is a good question… but you should ask that the OP, not me.

Comment: @Stano.. I need it as ID.. =)

Comment: @QKWS There are probably better things to use for an id. Using milliseconds makes a collision less likely, but not impossible.

Comment: `microtime();` is a better id, but if it should be a numeric id… don't know what else to use?!

Comment: My boss idea.Not mine =)