# ISO8601 Date in PHP with Format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmmmmmmZ

Tags: php, datetime, iso8601

I am trying to generate a timestamp in PHP for use with an API. I cannot seem to get the timestamp to format as it should. The proper format is:

**UTC ISO8601 DateTime format:** YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmmmmmmZ

**Example:** 2013-04-24T11:11:50.2829708Z

Edit, Let me clarify on the actual issue I am having:

The 'Z' Property is returning the timezone offset in seconds. I need the offset returned as date('c') returns it.

Example:
+01:00 instead of 3600

Is there a built in function for this in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP DateTime microseconds always returns 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169428/php-datetime-microseconds-always-returns-0)

Comment: Hey Matteo, I have read through those threads pretty well and updated my original question. I dont think the issue I am trying to solve is talked about in those.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for the [`DateTime::format` method](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) in combination with the `c` formatter or the [`DateTime::ISO8601` constant](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.iso8601):

```
$timestamp = new DateTime();
echo $timestamp->format('c'); // Returns ISO8601 in proper format
echo $timestamp->format(DateTime::ISO8601); // Works the same since const ISO8601 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO"
```

Comment: you can also just use the constant: `$timestamp->format(DateTime::ISO8601);` which is equal to `'Y-m-d\TH:i:sO'`

Comment: @prodigitalson Thanks, added your alternative with comments

Comment: I ended up using something similar to get to the final format I needed: `$t = microtime(true);
$micro = sprintf("%06d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000000);
$timeZoneOffset = strstr(date('c', $t), '+');
$d = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro,$t));
echo $d->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u" . $timeZoneOffset);`

Comment: Be careful because format `'c'` doesn't equal to `DateTime::ISO8601`.

Answer (score 4):

To print date in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) in PHP you can use the rather simple procedural style `date()` function like that:

```
$isoDate = date('c') // outputs 2017-10-18T22:44:26+00:00 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sO'
```

Or if you prefer to OOP style then you can use `DateTime()` like this:

```
$date = DateTime('2010-01-01');
echo date_format($date, 'c');
```

The list of date format/constants that PHP provides are [mentioned here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
const string ATOM = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;
const string COOKIE = "l, d-M-Y H:i:s T" ;
const string ISO8601 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO" ;
const string RFC822 = "D, d M y H:i:s O" ;
const string RFC850 = "l, d-M-y H:i:s T" ;
const string RFC1036 = "D, d M y H:i:s O" ;
const string RFC1123 = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
const string RFC2822 = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
const string RFC3339 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;
const string RSS = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
const string W3C = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;
```

So good thing is that we have ISO 8601 format in there. However, the value may not be same as you're expecting (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmmmmmmZ`). According to [ISO 8601 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), these are the valid formats:

```
2017-10-18T22:33:58+00:00
2017-10-18T22:33:58Z
20171018T223358Z
```

PHP probably prefers the first one. I was having somewhat similar problem dealing with dates between PHP and Javascript, because Javascript one has a trailing `Z` at the end. I ended up writing this to fix the issue:

```
$isoDate = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000') . 'Z'; // outputs: 2017-10-18T23:04:17.000Z
```

NOTE: the reason I have 3 decimals is I noticed that Javascript date is using this format, it may not be necessary for you.