# What is the highest date precision in PHP?

Tags: php, time

PHP has a number of ways of creating a timestamp. What is the most precise timestamp available?

Answer (score 4):

If by *precise*  you mean the smallest time increment possible, according to the PHP manual, you can get Unix timestamps in microseconds. As long as your operating system supports the `gettimeofday()` system call.

**[microtime()](http://php.net/microtime)**

Comment: `microtime(true)` loses precision in conversion to float. I think you only end up getting precision to 1/10th of a millisecond.

Answer (score 3):

The common method is `microtime(true)`, however it is probably not the most precise option.

1. `DateTime` isn't very good by default, and will give you seconds.

   ```
   $ php -r 'echo (new \DateTime())->format("U.u");'
   1483069259.000000
   ```
2. `microtime(true)` is better, and gives you approximate microseconds, but the float precision will do some rounding.

   ```
   $ php -r 'echo microtime(true);'
   1483069130.6427
   ```
3. `gettimeofday()` is better and gives you exact microseconds. You could use `microseconds(false)`, but handling the output is harder.

   ```
   $ php -r 'echo implode(".", array_slice(gettimeofday(), 0, 2));'
   1483070039.572630
   ```

So the best available `\DateTime` instance is, with full microsecond precision:

```
\DateTime::createFromFormat("U.u", implode(".", array_slice(gettimeofday(), 0, 2)))
```